# .NET analog of Ruby's CableReady + Stimulus Reflex? / SPA using HTML over Websockets

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

I am looking to so an SPA in an HTML-only environment (e.g. without JS).

I see in the Ruby world, [this SPA on websockets approach](https://alistapart.com/article/the-future-of-web-software-is-html-over-websockets/) is done with [CableReady and Stimulus Reflex](https://cableready.stimulusreflex.com/).

What are analogs in the .NET world to build an application in that way? (E.g. SPA, HTML based, minimal JS.)